# Updating a COLUMN Based on a Field Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

All, I have four columns (`A INT`, `B INT`, `C INT` and `D VARCHAR(1)`) in a table `TableName`. I want to move the values from column `C` to either `A` or `B` based upon the value in `D`. So if `D = 'A'` I want to move the value in `C` to `A`. How can I achieve this?

```
DECLARE @Column COLUMN;
UPDATE TableName 
SET (@Column = 
    (CASE 
        WHEN D = 'A' THEN A 
        WHEN D = 'B' THEN B
     END)) = C;
```

*Note. I understand the above is madness, but I am trying to express the problem as clearly as possible. I have also exhausted my search for answers. I am not new to SQL but this one has me stumped. Any help is as always, most appreciated.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here,

```
UPDATE TableName
SET A = (CASE WHEN D = 'A' THEN C ELSE A END),
    B = (CASE WHEN D = 'B' THEN C ELSE B END)
```

in this case, only 1 column will be changed  since `D` has only one value at a time.

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6816f/1)

Comment: John, thanks man! When you say only one with be moved, do you mean one record? Again, thanks for the reply it is most appreciated...

Comment: That's class. Cheers. Plus, I did not know about that website! Have a great weekend dood!